# Sufficient condition for injectivity of a linear transformation in terms of determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, determinant

For the revision in my Calculus III class, my teacher proposed the following question:

> Let $f: R^n \to R^m$ be linear, such that $f(\vec{x}) = A\vec{x}$,
> where $A \in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\vec{x} \in$
> $\mathbb{R}^n$. Which condition is needed and sufficient, in terms of
> determinants, for $f$ to be injective when: $m=n$, $m<n$ and $m>n$?

I kind of proved for the case that $m = n$, by using the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), that the determinant needs to be different of zero. But I really don't know how to argue for the other cases since I do not know about $m\times n$ matrix determinants. Can someone give me a direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $m>n$. Then $f$ is injective if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(f)=n$, and this occurs if and only if some $n\times n$ submatrix of $A$ has determinant different from $0$.

And if $m<n$, then $f$ is never injective, since the rank of any injective linear map is equal to the dimension of its domain and $\Bbb R^m$ contains no $n$-dimensional subspace.